# could not find xlsx file path during running of program

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop, winforms-interop

So, originally my program used a static spreadsheet named test, but to further enhance my program, I wanted it to make it to where the name within the textbox is the name of the file to use for the program; named: test.xlsx

So I believed I called the code properly here:

```
    public static string nameofexcelfile;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nameofexcelfile = textBox4.Text + ".xlsx";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFile();

    }

    public void OpenFile()
    {

    
        //Excel excel = new Excel(@"Test.xlsx", 1);
        Excel excel = new Excel(nameofexcelfile, 1);
        textBox1.Text = excel.ReadCell(1, 0);
        textBox2.Text = excel.ReadCell(1, 1);
        textBox3.Text = excel.ReadCell(3, 2);
        
    }
```

Here is my Excel.cs class file:

```
    internal class Excel
    {

        string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;



        public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            //this.path = path;
            //wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            this.path = Form1.nameofexcelfile;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Form1.nameofexcelfile);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];

        }

        public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
            else
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Within my Excel.cs class; I named a string and gave it the default location "" as the Documents folder, and this was named:

> string path = "";

This function below within my Excel.cs file is giving me an error of file not found:

```
public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
{
    //this.path = path;
    //wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
    this.path = Form1.nameofexcelfile;
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Form1.nameofexcelfile);
    ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];

}
```

originally, the function called the path as you see the 2 lines above commented it out. Since I want the Excel file to be found during the Form1 Textbox, how can I make this work. My error is shown below:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Sorry, we couldn't find
> .xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?'

[Error in OpenFile Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwK84.png)

Comment: Your program will look in the folder where your program is running. If you're running it from Visual Studio, that will be e.g. the `bin\Debug` folder under your project's folder. Where is the Excel file located?

Comment: Based on that code, the only time you set the file name is before the form is displayed. If you're expecting to use a file name entered by the user then you'd need to get the input after the user enters it. If you don't intend that then what's the `TextBox` for at all?

Comment: Documents folder but that should not be the issue as it called the test.xlsx from the documents folder just fine when it was a static file. What I'm wanting to do is leave the location as is but not have the file statically named: test.xlsx. For example, if I had a excel file named "2020 purchases", it would read that file or any other file that is named in textbox 4

Comment: @jmcilhinney that could be my issue, since the goal is for the program to run and while it is running, the user can enter the name of the excel file and then use that excel file?

Comment: @jmcilhinney although I wouldn't know where or which code to move around and where it would go for it to allow the program to work correctly. I just tried switching the nameofexcelfile = textBox4.Text + ".xlsx"; down but it still did not work

Comment: You need to think about the logic first, rather than just throwing code at the wall and hoping it sticks. We've already established that getting text from a `Textbox` before the form has even been displayed makes no sense. Think about what you want to actually happen in the application. The user enters the file name into the `Textbox` and then what? Do they click a `Button`? I wonder whether you could put the code in the `Click` event handler of the `Button`? Think about the logic and write code to implement that logic.